# .Net 1.1 framework Container

Tags: c#, list, vector, .net-1.1

I must to use `1.1 .NET` version Framework (`c#`).

What can I use as Vector,List (object container)?

I saw that is not possible to use List or Vector

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Can you share your code so far?

Comment: Why are you using .NET 1.1? Legacy system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is what you're looking for.

Comment: And, I'm sorry you have to use .NET 1.1. :(

Answer (score 1):

You could use an ArrayList.

However, generics are not supported in .NET 1.1, so you would need to cast every time you access an item